# "Multipurpose" Model, View and Controller - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.1

I have in my application 10 different tables, but which has the same structure ... `id` | `name` | `description`. For each table have the laravel the `Model`, the `Controller` and registration, listing and editing Views. I wonder if you have any way to use the same `Model`, `Controller` and `View` to manage it all, or is to minimize this in some way as it has many similar files and do not think it's really necessary, but I lack knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need 10 different tables for same structure? Make it 1 and assign type for differentiate.

Comment: I don't know ... I think this is a simple and optimal solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm waiting for the minimum time